# MySQL Workbench apparmor error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mysql, apparmor

When I try to launch MySQL Workbench I get the following AppArmor error

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![sql1][2]][2]

When I run `sudo aa-status` I get below result

```
48 profiles are in enforce mode.
   :
   :
   :
   :
   snap-update-ns.mysql-workbench-community
   snap.mysql-workbench-community.mysql-workbench-community
```

When I try to disable it get below error

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/snap.mysql-workbench-community.mysql-workbench-community /etc/apparmor.d/disable/


sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/snap.mysql-workbench-community.mysql-workbench-community
File /etc/apparmor.d/snap.mysql-workbench-community.mysql-workbench-community not found, skipping...
```

I am having the same problem but I am running 22.10 !!